# Find the radius given only a few variables

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I'm writing a program that allows someone to generate a vertical road segment in 3D given a HEIGHT and an ANGLE. The road starts off flat, curves (to the ANGLE), has a brief straight segment (SEGLEN), curves again, and then goes straight again. My problem is, I'm hoping to figure out a way to find the RADIUS of the circle without asking the user for it.

[image: Descriptive Picture]

I believe it's possible to figure out because there seems to be a relationship between the RADIUS of the curve and the HEIGHT of the road. Obviously, as the radius decreases or increases, the arc length does too which would push the SEGLEN up or down. However, the arc length (of both curve) needs to be just right to fulfill the HEIGHT requirement of the road.

A radius too big would make the road too high. A radius too small would make the road too small. I can't change the ANGLE or HEIGHT. So how do I find what I need to generate the curve?

The only thing I can think of is to also have the user input a SEGLEN, but preferably not. Even then, I'm not sure how I would use SEGLEN to get what I need.

Comment: I don't get exactly what you want. One exercise would be to get to the height with two arcs, with no flat length between them. Otherwise, you can take whatever arc you want (well, not completly true, since an arc with a very big radius might lead you too high before reaching the angle), you will be able to reach the angle you want. Is there any constraint on the total lenght (horizontal) of the road?

Comment: @Martigan Sorry if I wasn't clear. So I've got a HEIGHT and I've got an ANGLE. If there weren't any curves between the SEGLEN's and we were just connecting them end to end you'd have a sharp angle  which you can't obviously drive across, so I have to smooth the transition. This means inserting a curve at the joint, which obviously takes away from the remaining height left for the segment to exist. Does that clarify things?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I actually need to know what the SEGLEN is now before continuing. Otherwise there are multiple sizes that would work for both the SEGLEN and RADIUS inside there. Defining one should force the other to conform somehow. There is no restriction on LENGTH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two of h=HEIGHT, r=RADIUS, and s=SEGLEN as well as a=ANGLE to get there.  Each curved part rises $h'=r(1-\cos a)$, so $h=2r(1-\cos a)+s \sin a$.  That gives you one equation to determine one variable.

Comment: I didn't understand the application of the provided formula, but marking correct because I now realize I need HEIGHT, RADIUS, and ANGLE to proceed. I need SEGLEN as well of course, but it will scale based on RADIUS now.

Comment: You can solve the formula to determine SEGLEN from the others.  It will be $s=\frac 1{\sin a}(h-2r(1-\cos a))$  What don't you understand?  The trig functions come from drawing triangles.